# Does a word rhyme with itself?

Tags: rhymes

In other words, does rhyming work reflexively?

Do "potato" and "potato" rhyme?

Is the following (admittedly cumbersome) limerick valid?

> *An issue with rhymes confused me much 
>  So I used the internet as a crutch 
>  I went to a site 
>  The Stack Exchange site 
>  And
>   used it as my crutch*

Comment: [Edward Lear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limerick_%28poetry%29#Edward_Lear), who popularized limericks, did frequently rhyme a word with itself, but usually in the first and last line of the poem.

Comment: I wanted to know if a rhyme/Could repeat the last word as a rhyme/So I made up a rhyme/That ended in 'rhyme'/And queried the state of the rhyme.

Comment: It doesn't work. Nobody knows why. [But there are theories](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/113802/15299).

Comment: Didn't want to hijack the question, but how about something a little bit more like Edward Lear? "I found rhymes confused me so much / That I searched far and wide for a crutch. / I found I could cite / The Stack Exchange site / Which I thought very good as a crutch." Feel free to use that if you like.

Answer (score 18):

By the formal definition of 'rhyme' (matching the last few sounds), yes, a word rhymes with it self.

But to actually use it in a poem is jarring in its lack of imagination. So it violates the rules of artfulness.

Comment: Agreed. In the case of the OP's limerick, it also violates the conventional limerick format.

Comment: Do you have a source for this formal definition of rhyme? I can imagine defining "rhyme" in such a way as to exclude identical words.

Comment: @sumelic In fact most definitions I find from a quick search are along the lines of "a word that has the same sound as another." which would imply different rather than the same to me.

Comment: "Rules of artfulness?"  That's a sad idea.  Yes, words, on a technical level, rhyme with themselves, and this can be done intentionally in aesthetic contexts without it being bad or violating any "rules."  See the much better answer posted by @Related.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm tempted to think /occasionally/ ending lines with the same word is OK.  It certainly doesn't constitute breaking the rules of rhyme as far as poetry is concerned.  Indeed, such ruling would complicate the process of writing out the rhyme scheme of a poem.

Comment: @MartinSmith That sounds to me like a definition of a homophone.

Comment: To elaborate on my earlier comment, let's look at one of Mr Lear's limericks.

There was an Old Man with a beard, [A]
Who said, "It is just as I feared!— [A]
Two Owls and a Hen, [B]
Four Larks and a Wren, [B]
Have all built their nests in my beard. [???]

If you consider identical words to rhyme, the last line is straightforwardly A.  But if not, you have a problem in that "beard" rhymes with "feared" but not "beard", which are both A.  So how do you write it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes a word can rhyme with itself *and* work effectively/artistically. Case in point, John Lennon's Imagine:

*You may say I'm a dreamer / But I'm not the only one / I hope someday you'll join us / And the world will live as one*

Comment: Ah, so _that's_ why that song always annoys me :)

Comment: This is a matter of opinion. Rhythmically speaking, The last three words of the refrain are the weakest part of the song, not just because of the repeated word but also because John always stretched "world" over two beats and jammed "live-as-one" together on a single beat. Rhythmically it makes more sense to give "world", "live", and "one" a beat each, in the same rhythm as the second line, "not", "only", and "one". I say this as someone who loves this song.

Comment: This is called an "Identical Rhyme". It's used by famous poets as well.

Answer (score 0):

it can but when doing a limerick has to rhyme with a word other than itself. Plus, limericks have to go in a 8-9, 8-9, 5-6, 5-6, 8-9 syllable format. Yours is a 9, 10, 5, 5, 6

Comment: I guess your format could be right that is just how I learned to do it.

Comment: Just for the record, my poem from last year (see the comments under the OP's question) totally satisfies the syllable requirements that Joe Father identifies here. I admit that the meter isn't perfect—but it _rhymes_.

Comment: Counting syllables works for haiku, But for limericks it just won't do. Look at this poor sample As a bad example. Limericks of iambs are untrue.

Comment: @Peter Shor I recommend a trip to Blarney Castle. ASAP.

Answer (score -2):

No, a word doesn't rhyme with itself. Both are the same word, so therefore it's just repetitive. You only think it rhymes because you hear the exact same sound.

Comment: Hearing the same sound is one (reasonable) definition of a rhyme.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - No, because if a word has *too much* of the same sound it doesn't rhyme, to the "normal" ear.

Comment: I believe a word rhyming with itself is a form of "identical rhyme."