# Is there a term for sets of words that alliterate and rhyme with each other?

Tags: single-word-requests, rhymes, alliteration

[Can English have words that are both alliterations and also rhyme?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146495/can-english-have-words-that-are-both-alliterations-and-also-rhyme) is looking for the sets of words that I want to put a specific term to.

Sets of words such as:

- [divide, deride](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/428540/115108), decide
- [alliance, appliance](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/404727/115108)
- [dusty, dirty](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/428537/115108)

I'm wanting the missing word in

> These words X with each other

where 'X' is something more comprehensive than "alliterate" or "rhyme" because they don't encompass that the other pattern is occurring too.

[Minimal pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair) is close, but that allows single phoneme variation in *any* location, not just the middle, *and* wouldn't allow a hypothetical set of four-phoneme words that vary in their middle two.

Comment: Isn't it "poetic" or "creative" use?

Comment: @WeatherVane - The "poetic" in the title might be irrelevant. Not sure? I'm wanting the missing word in "These words [X] with each other", where X is something comprehensive than "alliterate" or "rhyme" because they don't encompass that the other pattern is occurring too.

Comment: Perhaps the words 'resonate'.

Comment: Here are all the rhyme types: https://www.dailywritingtips.com/types-of-rhyme/ end, internal, slant, rich, identical and eye rhymes. Yours are all end rhymes.

Comment: minimal pair is not a poetry definition. It's linguistics.

Comment: @Lambie - That's confirmation that I should remove the word "poetic" then, thanks!

Comment: Yes. Initial clusters, like [_kl-_](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf), are called "Assonances", and verb + offset (like [_-əmp_](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/-ump.pdf)) are called "Rimes". The terms are due to Bolinger; [further details here](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/WomenMen&BristlyThings.pdf).

Comment: The Stack Overflow post you include uses the term "alliterative rhyme"

Comment: @user3326047 - Thanks for pointing that out! I guess that'd be the best I could do, and would accept that as a frame challenge! Although, it "alliterative rhyme scheme" being used to describe Beowulf and Piers Plowman muddy the definition of "alliterative rhyme". - https://journals.ysu.am/index.php/arm-fol-angl/article/view/Vol.10_No.1-2_2014_pp.054-062

Comment: I suggest there is not, partly because only the first of those sets is a proper alliteration.