# Is there a name for this kind of loose pseudo alliteration? for example, gold -> glitter, crown -> king

Tags: terminology, poetry, alliteration

In Norse poetry, to the fastidious skald, a word like **t**ake is not considered to alliterate with **tr**ain, but a word like **tr**ack does alliterate with a word like **tr**oop, and **t**ear does alliterate with **t**in.

However, such words considered non alliterative are still clearly related, though not identical, in their initial consonant sounds.

My question is if there is a name for this kind of thing; of following up "**pr**etty" with "**p**icture", as opposed to "**pr**etty" with "**pr**ank".

Loose alliteration? Nigh alliteration? False alliteration?
as opposed to strict, full, or true alliteration (or simply: alliteration).

Cultures, individuals, and artistic movements have their own differing standards. Some would say that **pr** an **p** do alliterate, but even then, it is clearly a slightly different kind of alliteration compared to **p** and **p**.
I want to know if there are names for these two kinds of alliteration, and what they are.

Comment: In Old English poetry, *gold* was considered to alliterate with *glitter*. For example, Beowulf starts *Hwæt.
We Gardena in geardagum, //
**þeod**cyninga, **þrym** gefrunon.*

So these are two different kinds of alliteration (i.e., you shouldn't call the alliteration in Beowulf *false* alliteration). I don't know if there are names for them.

Comment: And the -g- sound can be hard (velar) or soft (palatal): ***gl**idon ofer **g**arsecg **ge**ofon yþum*

Comment: Or ***G**ardena **ge**ardagum*

Comment: If this is specifically about terminology in Norse poetry, you're asking in the wrong place.

Comment: In advertisind we'd say ... clever copywriters always alliterate.

Comment: Your question title appears to contain an incorrect assumption, and hence is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Alliteration" is a broad term, not a specific one. It covers both systems described in the question.

To refer generally to alliteration that matches the entire syllable onset, I would suggest using a descriptive phrase like "full onset cluster alliteration" (which could be contrasted to "initial consonant alliteration").

The specific rules about what counts as valid and invalid alliteration depend on what tradition the poet is working in, as you note, so it isn't clear to use the wording "strict, full, or true alliteration (or simply: alliteration)" to refer to the system you describe in the first paragraph.* It would be clearest to specify what tradition you mean. I'm curious what tradition of Norse poetry has this rule, since I see examples of Norse poems that appear not to follow it:

> From the Karlevi runestone in Oland, c. 1000 AD
>
> > **F**olginn liggr hinns fylgðu
> >
> > **fl**estr vissi þat mestar
> >
> > **d**aeðir dolga Þruðar
> >
> > **dr**augr í þeimsi haugi [...]

(http://viking.archeurope.info/index.php?page=drottkvatt-noble-warrior-s-metre)

> From Haraldskvaeði
>
> > **Hl**aðnir oru holða
> >
> > ok **hv**itra skjalda
> >
> > vigra vestroenna
> >
> > ok valskra sverða;
> >
> > **gr**enjuðu berserkir,
> >
> > **g**uðr var þeim á sinnum [...]

(http://viking.archeurope.info/index.php?page=malahattr-or-metre-of-speeches)

The clusters  st-, sp- and sc- show special behavior in Old English verse, and I would guess also in Norse. I wrote more about alliteration in my answer here: [Can English have words that are both alliterations and also rhyme?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/428540/77227)

---

*However, interestingly, I see another poster on the writing Stack Exchange shared your impression that alliteration on the same consonant using different onset clusters is "not a pure alliteration" (user5645's answer to [Mixing dissonance and alliteration?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/26449/mixing-dissonance-and-alliteration), describing "Sweetly, slimily, and softly")

Comment: Is there some reason you emboldened the onsets of just some of the alliterations, not all of them? There are nearly always three per caesura-separated pair of two-beat halves. Unless you have some other purpose here such as only illustrating matches with and without a following liquid, it it were me I would also so mark the missing *fylgðu* and *dolga* on the runetone verse, as well as *holda* and the three *v-* words from the other verse.

Comment: @tchrist: I just did the first ones that showed the non-matching onsets. It seemed simplest and I wasn't sure about the specific rules applying to all alliterations in the poems

Comment: Original poster here. I got the idea that alliteration with the same consonant but different onset clusters was looked down on in Norse poetry from the foreword to my copy of the poetic edda (in Swedish), written by the translator.

Because you have shown examples to the contrary, I have changed my mind on this, and I will be on the lookout for such alliteration in any future Norse poetry that I read.

Comment: “The clusters st-, sp- and sc- show special behavior in Old English verse, and I would guess also in Norse.” — I can confirm this. The limitation referred to in the question only applied to clusters beginning in s-, in particular these three, but also usually sm- and occasionally others. Egill Skalla-Grímsson (there is no more authoritative skald) starts his _Sonatorrek_ with the following lines: Mjǫk erum **tr**egt / **t**ungu at hrœra.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about **English**,

```
gold -> glitter
crown -> king
pretty -> picture
```

That is called "alliteration."

```
Is there a name for this?
```

"Alliteration."

You can glance at the Oxford English Dictionary definition,

> the occurrence of the **same letter** or sound at the beginning of adjacent or closely connected words: the alliteration of “**sweet** birds **sang**”

Alliteration is used very widely in English, one of a million examples in movie titles "Pretty in Pink".

(Your question title appears to contain an incorrect assumption, and hence is a bit confusing.)