# Rhyming with words

Tags: single-word-requests

If I want to rhyme with a word like 'time' would 'overtime' or 'anytime' count as a rhyme with 'time', saying that 'anytime' and 'overtime' have the word 'time' in it. (This goes for any other words)

Comment: that would be a pretty lame rhyme. This question is answered here https://english.stackexchange.com/q/45712/17611

Comment: See also [In what sort of rhyme do matching consonants precede last stressed vowels?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223631)

Comment: Black Sabbath reckon it's okay. http://www.lyricsfreak.com/b/black+sabbath/war+pigs_20019418.html

Answer (score 1):

A syllable consists of two parts: an 'onset' and a 'rime'.  It is the final rimes that should match to make a rhyme.  Penultimate rimes and syllables may also match; however, the onsets that precede those patterns should not match.

Word breaks (white space) are of minor importance in speech, so 'overtime' works the same as 'over time' for rhyming.

Thus 'great office holder' rhymes perfectly with 'late office holder' and weakly with 'bait off his shoulder', but not with either 'green office holder' or 'grate off his shoulder'.

Comment: As NVZ has said, 'Please explain your answer, preferably with some supporting statements and references. While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.'

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how strict you intend to be about your rhyming scheme. I would count it as repetition, not rhyming, but it can still fit just fine into a rhyme scheme.